# How can I quickly capture all of a websites MathML to use in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, website, mathjax, microsoft-word-365, mathml

I create mathematics workbooks in Microsoft Word. Typing in each equation is slow but faster than LaTex. So, I often copy content from a website like [LibreTexts](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Map%3A_Calculus_-_Early_Transcendentals_(Stewart)/12%3A_Vectors_and_The_Geometry_of_Space/12.05%3A_Equations_of_Lines_and_Planes). If I copy a section that contains equations it comes out garbled.

So, I go to each equation, right click, hover over Show Math As, select MathML code, select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), close window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>), go to word (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), paste as plain text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), go back to Chrome browser (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), then repeat the process.

This can be faster than typing by hand, but there has to be an easier way. There was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709187/browser-to-display-mathml-code-instead-of-equation?newreg=3904d93ba0554a41a0e0f01acd240c6b) similar to this one, but I don't know what extension was referred to and I don't know Java.

If your solutions contains the step "learn basic Java here", that is fine.

Comment: Excellent question IMO. I have limited knowledge, but it seems that Word's LaTeX support is primitive. OTOH, mathjax seems to do an excellent job of converting LaTeX to MathML, but only via a dialog box. Without going into the gory details, I'm not convinced you could do anything unless their API (which appears not to be documented) can help scan an HTML and return a number of MathML equations. Copying HTML text into Word and trying to convert equations there seems not to work because Word basically does not recognise the JS/LaTex libraries specified on the web page (whereas mathjax seems to).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Wikipedia, press edit, then copy past from there, it worked for me.

For example, I go to this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_concept?action=edit&veswitched=1&oldid=1191643154) and copy and pasted this part here:

```
let <math>S_G</math> be the set of [[strategy profile]]s of <math>G</math>. A ''solution concept'' is an element of the direct product <math>\Pi_{G \in \Gamma}2^{S_G};</math> ''i.e''., a function <math>F: \Gamma \rightarrow \bigcup\nolimits_{G \in \Gamma} 2^{S_G}</math> such that <math>F(G) \subseteq S_G</math> for all <math>G \in \Gamma.</math>
```

This works for AI chat bots like Claude and chatGPT if you want to ask deeper questions.